# Remove button to remove selected row from listview JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx

I am trying to create a reminder/to do list gui. I was able to make the add Event button to work but then i wasn't able to make the delete event button to work.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        dateDate.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    }

    @FXML
    Button btnAdd;
    @FXML
    Button btnDel;
    @FXML
    TextField tfEvent;
    @FXML
    DatePicker dateDate;
    @FXML
    ListView<LocalEvent> lvEvent;

    ObservableList<LocalEvent> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private void addEvent(Event a) {
        list.add(new LocalEvent(dateDate.getValue(), tfEvent.getText()));
        lvEvent.setItems(list);
        clean();
    }

    private void clean() {
        dateDate.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        tfEvent.setText(null);
    }

    @FXML
    private void delEvent(Event a) {
        int selectedID = lvEvent.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        lvEvent.getItems().remove(selectedID);


    }
}
```

Comment: Try `getSelectedItem()` instead.

Comment: This looks correct. What actually happens? Are there errors?  Can you confirm the `delEvent()` method is getting called? What value does `selectedID` have?

Comment: Oh, my bad, the delEvent( ) wasn’t getting called previously, it has some errors that i’ve figured out. Thanks!